# How to copy&paste a Word (>= 2007) equation from a table cell with Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste, equation

I have a table in Word 2010 with equations in the second column. I want to copy each equation from the cells and paste it, e.g. at the start of the document. But it didn't work out. Here's the code:

```
Sub CopyEquation()
    Dim objEq As OMath

    Set Cols = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2)


    For Each aCell In Cols.Cells
       objEq = aCell.Range.OMaths(1)  'Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
    Next aCell

    'insert at start of document
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).OMaths.Add objEq  'Runtime error '13': Type mismatch
End Sub
```

The errors are mentioned as comments. For the second one, I used an example OMath as [mentioned in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821988.aspx).

Comment: what if you add `Set` to error line like `Set objEq = ....`?

Comment: @KazJaw Oh, yes. Thanks for answering this somehow stupid question. Sorry, I'm a newbie in VBA (-; better trained in Matlab and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found it. This works:

```
Sub CopyEquation()
    Dim objEq As OMath
    Dim objRange As Range

    ' Select first table, second column
    Set Cols = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2)

    For Each aCell In Cols.Cells
       ' Copy in each cell the first math environment ...
       Set objEq = aCell.Range.OMaths(1)
       objEq.Range.Copy

       ' ... and paste it at the start of the document
       ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Paste
    Next aCell
End Sub
```